# Service Bus for Windows 1.0 error

Tags: servicebus

I've started investigating the Service Bus for Windows 1.0 to create a local Service Bus for our applications and I followed the example shown here for my first attempt at using the bus:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj542433(v=azure.10).aspx

However, when I run the sample I receive the following error(s):

> The token provider was unable to provide a security token while
>   accessing
>   'https://{machineName.domainName}/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/$STS/Windows/'.
>   Token provider returned message: 'The underlying connection was
>   closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.'

with an inner exception of:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Everything that I have searched on relates to problems around the locally generated certificate, etc. This isn't that. Browsing to the STS using 'https://{machineName.domainName}:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/' returns an atom feed of queues/topics. Any help moving this forward to get at least the sample working?

Source code (99% identical to sample link above; only stylistic differences and ServerFQDN address, which is local and matches the data from installation):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace ServiceBus1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string ServerFQDN = "{machineName}.{domain}.net";
        private const int HttpPort = 9355;
        private const int TcpPort = 9354;
        private const string ServiceNamespace = "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace";

        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var connBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    ManagementPort = HttpPort,
                    RuntimePort = TcpPort
                };
            connBuilder.Endpoints.Add( new UriBuilder { Scheme = "sb", Host = ServerFQDN, Path = ServiceNamespace }.Uri );
            connBuilder.StsEndpoints.Add( new UriBuilder { Scheme = "https", Host = ServerFQDN, Path = ServiceNamespace }.Uri );

            var messageFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString( connBuilder.ToString() );
            var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString( connBuilder.ToString() );

            const string queueName = "ServiceBusQueueSample";

            if ( namespaceManager == null )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "\nUnexpectedError: NamespaceManager is NULL" );
                return;
            }

            if ( namespaceManager.QueueExists( queueName ) )
            {
                namespaceManager.DeleteQueue( queueName );
            }

            namespaceManager.CreateQueue( queueName );

            var myQueueClient = messageFactory.CreateQueueClient( queueName );

            try
            {
                // send a message to the queue
                var sendMessage = new BrokeredMessage( "Hello World!" );
                myQueueClient.Send( sendMessage );

                // receive the message from the queue
                var receivedMessage = myQueueClient.Receive( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 ) );

                if ( receivedMessage != null )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Message received: Body = {0}", receivedMessage.GetBody<string>() );
                    receivedMessage.Complete(); // releases msg lock and removes from queue?
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Unexpected exception {0}", e );
            }
            finally
            {
                if ( messageFactory != null )
                {
                    messageFactory.Close();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "Press ENTER to clean up and exit." );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that you are following a sample, but please also post your own code.

Comment: After breakpointing and walking thru everything and checking values against the configured farm settings, it turns out I had missed the `Port = HttpPort` portion of the STS UriBuilder **(facepalm)**. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I figured that was what was happening, based on the URLs you provided initially.  I'm glad you were able to track it down.

Comment: I have used `Port = HttpPort portion of the STS UriBuilder ` still getting same error ?